# Extracting a link from html using python and BeautifulSoup: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi there I am using python 3 beautifulsoup to try and extract the link. It works most of the time but every now and then it cant find the schema.

Code I have looks like this(part of a larger body):

```
self.schema = self.soup.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef']).get('xlink:href')

self.namespaces = {}

for k in self.soup.find('html').attrs:
    if k.startswith("xmlns") or ":" in k:
        self.namespaces[k] = self.soup.find('html')[k].split(" ")
```

has no issue finding the schema in this kind of stuff:

```
<ix:references>
    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="https://xbrl.frc.org.uk/FRS-102/2014-09-01/FRS-102-2014-09-01.xsd" />
</ix:references>
```

but it cant find xlink:href in these ones:

```
<references>
    <schemaRef xlink:href="https://xbrl.frc.org.uk/FRS-102/2014-09-01/FRS-102-2014-09-01.xsd" xlink:type="simple" xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"/>
</references>
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-da0992ab9ae8> in <module>
     96 
     97         with open(filename,encoding="utf8") as a:
---> 98             x = Parser(a)
     99             r = json.dumps(x.to_table(), indent=4)
    100             jsondata = json.loads(r)

~\OneDrive\Desktop\parser\core.py in __init__(self, f, raise_on_error)
     21         self.errors = []
     22 
---> 23         self._get_schema()
     24 
     25         self._get_contexts()

~\OneDrive\Desktop\parser\core.py in _get_schema(self)
     47         self.schema = self.soup.find(
     48 
---> 49             ['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef']).get('xlink:href')
     50 
     51         self.namespaces = {}

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: I'd rather think it means your `self.soup.find('html')` is `None`.

Comment: The error is high lighted at:  ['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef']).get('xlink:href') so I don't think it even gets that far

Comment: In the second example, is there a space before `xlink:type`?

Comment: yes, I think that's just formatting on here

Comment: The error message suggests that @Błotosmętek is right. Include the full traceback and we will see for sure.

Comment: Thanks. That's a different error to the one you mention: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'". Now it's clear that `self.soup.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef'])` is returning None.

Comment: Sorry, but thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

From your error trace back, the line call

```
self.soup.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef'])
```

is returning None. To protect against this, you should test the result before executing `get`, i.e.:

```
data = self.soup.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef'])
if data is not None:
    self.schema = data.get('xlink:href')
```

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea though why it cant find schemaRef when it's clearly there?

Comment: So maybe if I did something like this: 

resources = self.soup.find(['ix:resources', 'resources'])

self.schema = resources.find(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef']).get('xlink:href')

Comment: Yes, if your `soup` object has already found `ix:references`, it should also try to find `references`. I recommend posting the relevant part of your code to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

@dspencer So this returns the correct schema.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("F:\ErrorFolder\06647909.html", "r") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
    resources = soup.find(['ix:references', 'references'])
    #print(resources)
    for s in resources.find_all(['link:schemaRef', 'schemaRef', 'schemaref']):
        x = s.get('xlink:href')
        print(x)
```

So I just need to change stuff around it seems the real issue might be the schemaref vs schemaRef

Thank you so much you've been really helpful